# How can I read using FlatFileReader but write only to ExecutionContext

Tags: spring-batch

I want to read read a text file to build a map and place it into the ExecutionContext for later reference.

I thought to start out using chunk-processng to read the file, the process it, but I don't need the FlatFileItemWriter to write to a file.  However, bean initializing requires I set a resource on the writer.

Am I going about this wrong?  Is chunk=process the wrong approach.  Creating a tasklet my be wiser, but I liked that SpringBatch would read my file for me.  With a tasklet, I'd have to write the code to open and process the text file.  Right?

Advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing (I'm new) was create a Tasklet, and have it also implement the StepExecutionListener interface.  Worked like a charm.  It's reading a comma-delimited file by lines, plucking out the second column.  I created an 'enum'  for my ExecutionContext map keys.  Basically, this below:

```
public class ProcessTabcPermitsTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    private Resource resource;
    private int linesToSkip;
    private Set<String> permits = new TreeSet<String>();

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)  throws Exception {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader((new FileReader(resource.getFile())));
        String line = null;
        int lines = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (++lines <= linesToSkip)
                continue;

            String[] s = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(line);
            permits.add(s[TABC_COLUMNS.PERMIT.ordinal()]);

        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    /**
     * @param file
     *            the file to set
     */
    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    /**
     * @param linesToSkip
     *            the linesToSkip to set
     */
    public void setLinesToSkip(int linesToSkip) {
        this.linesToSkip = linesToSkip;
    }


    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put(EXECUTION_CONTEXT.TABC_PERMITS.toString(), permits);
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

}
```